# Configure production server on headless ubuntu 14.04 VM

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tomcat, server, geoserver

I'm trying to set up apache tomcat + geoserver on a vanilla headless ubuntu 14.04 VM. New to configuring servers. I followed instructions [here](http://www.negengec.com/2014/09/run-geoserver-ubuntu-tomcat7/).

Everything installs correctly (JDK, tomcat, etc), and I set the required paths (JAVA_HOME), but I'm unable to view the welcome screen when I navigate to my.IP.address:8080 The error message is simply "Site can't be reached / server took too long to respond".

Here is the output of `netstat -ln` call:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6187            0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 172.16.1.99:123         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*
udp6       0      0 :::8535                 :::*
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8194     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9277     /tmp/ssh-7c5IXKrDG2/agent.1009
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1550     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17930    /tmp/ssh-YibKLf82uf/agent.9563
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17991    /tmp/ssh-7sKu9hrWGj/agent.9614
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7996     /tmp/ssh-P39kZuqghs/agent.965
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     1672     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6989     @/com/ubuntu/mountall/server/
```

I also tried the geoserver binaries which come bundled with a Jetty application server [found here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/linux.html). The problem seems to be in accessing the 8080 port, as I have been unable to successfully load a page at my.IP.address:8080 using any method. Am I missing something regarding access to remote headless VMS via a web browser?

UPDATE:

I switched to a jetty server that comes bundled with geoserver and am able to access the geoserver on localhost:8080/geoserver from ubuntu command line using w3m. Since I want to access the server from other machines, I edited the jetty.xml file, adding `<Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="xx.yy.zzz.ww"/></Set>`

Now when I start the geoserver, the init dialogue reads `Started SelectChannelConnector@xx.yy.zzz.ww:8080`

If I browse to //my.ip.address:8080 using w3m on ubuntu, I can access the server. However, when I try this from another machine, I get the same "connection timed out" error

Comment: Do you have a firewall running and does it have a rule for 8080?

Comment: calling `ufw status` returns `inactive`

Comment: calling `iptables -L` returns:

    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: i did `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` but still no luck from an outside machine

Comment: also did the same command but for ip6tables